# Slicing and indexing in Theano

Tags: python, slice, theano

I want to index a Tensor Variable in Theano as such:

- x  has type theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable (e.g. `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`)

I want to get `[[1,2],[4,5],[7,8]]`, and `[[2,3],[5,6],[8,9]]`.

For a numpy varaible I would simply do `x[:,0:-1]` and `x[:,1:x.shape[0]]`, respectively, but I can't figure out how to get the results I want in Theano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do it the same way in Theano as you are doing in numpy:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.imatrix('x')
y = x[:, 0: -1]
z = x[:, 1: x.shape[0]]

f = theano.function([x], y)
g = theano.function([x], z)

x_ = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(f(x_))
print(g(x_))
```